# translate gsl_ran_hypergeometric_pdf(k, n1, n2, t) to boost::math::hypergeometric_distribution

Tags: c++, boost, statistics, gsl

How do I translate this C++ program that uses hypergeometric
distribution functions from the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Hypergeometric-Distribution.html

into a C++ program that instead uses similar functions from the [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/)?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
  unsigned int n1 = 256;
  unsigned int n2 = 1583;
  unsigned int t = 300;
  unsigned int k = 40;
  std::cout << gsl_ran_hypergeometric_pdf(k, n1, n2, t)
            << std::endl
            << gsl_cdf_hypergeometric_P(k, n1, n2, t)
            << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a translation into Boost functions:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/distributions/hypergeometric.hpp>
#include <boost/math/policies/policy.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  unsigned int n1 = 256;
  unsigned int n2 = 1583;
  unsigned int t = 300;
  unsigned int k = 40;
  boost::math::hypergeometric_distribution<double> hg_dist(n1, t, n1 + n2);
  std::cout << boost::math::pdf<double>(hg_dist, k)
            << std::endl
            << boost::math::cdf<double>(hg_dist, k)
            << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For more info see
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/hypergeometric_dist.html